# MariaDB connector python get executed query

Tags: python, mariadb

Does the python [MariaDB connector](https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/conpy1.0/) has api to print out the actual query that it runs, after it has finished inserting the parameters (in the prepared statements)?
Similarly to the solution in the [python-mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/): `cursor._executed`. Sometimes logging query template and arguments is not enough in case of tracking some client compatibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

`cursor.statement` Does the job, according to [documentation](https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/conpy/api/statement/#conpy-api-statement):

> The last executed statement. (read only) Displays the last executed SQL statement. (read-only)

Comment: unfortunately for query templates it returns last template (without parsing the arguments)

Comment: MariaDB Connector/Python uses binary protocol,which means arguments are not parsed and substituted. Client sends the statement for preparation followed by an execute packet containing parameters in binary presentation.